# My server is returning "301 moved permanently" to some sketchy site

Tags: nginx, malware

`ping` returns the correct IP address, but a `curl` to the IP address or domain returns:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't even have nginx installed. I'm running a docker image (Computer Vision Annotation Tool) with a Caddy server for reverse proxy on Ubuntu 22. It worked fine, I shut down the server (EC2 instance) for a few days, booted it again and now it redirects.

Have I been hacked?

Comment: This forum is about running a website and there may not be the server skills you are seeking.  I have flagged this question to be migrated to Server Fault

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, Ping only resolves to IP addresses, it does *not* access the upper OSI layers like Web Services.  Therefore, while Ping can identify that your server's network card is responding, it has no idea that your server runs a website.

Comment: It probably depends on what the "sketch site" is.   I wonder if NGINX is running on the Ubuntu server and binding to port 80 (or 443) and so its not available to Docker.  Log onto the server and execute 'fuser -v -n tcp 80'  (or 443 if you are connecting on port 443) and see what process is associated with it, then work back from there.